# SQL, php pdo and retreiving table rows

Tags: php, html, sql, pdo

I have a really big problem right now and I cant find a solution for it, so I was hoping to get some help.

I am selecting specific columns from a table using the following query

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT Info FROM Info;');
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Then I am outputting it using php

```
<div id="two">
<?php
if(!$resTwo)
echo"No Content Available Yet..";
else
echo "<ul>";
foreach($resTwo AS $val) {
echo "<tr>";
foreach($val AS $val1) {
    echo "<td>$val1</td>";
  }
}
echo "</ul>";
$db = null; 
?>
</div>
```

Now here comes the problem. This script works perfect for one page, but the thing is that I have several pages that look exactly the same, and the only thing that differs is the content I have added from the db. So I would prefer if I could avoid writing a new script in every page and instead using some sort of indexing of the SELECT made above.

If i wanted to solve this I would have to change the following per page

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT Info FROM Info WHERE rowid = 1;');
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT Info FROM Info WHERE rowid = 2;');
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT Info FROM Info WHERE rowid = 3;');
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT Info FROM Info WHERE rowid = 4;');
```

...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480555/database-php-pdo-and-html

Comment: Not sure if this will help but you can do: `WHERE rowid IN(1,2,3,4)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get an parameter by $_GET or $_POST and use it in your query. See:

```
$var = $_GET['id'];
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT Info FROM Info WHERE rowid = :RowId');
$stmt->bindParam(":RowId", $var, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute(); $res = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 1):

- Add a php function and add the following code in a common.php:

  ```
  <php    

  function getRowContentResultSet($rowId)
  {

      $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT Info FROM Info WHERE rowid = :rowId');
      $stmt->execute(array(':rowId' => $rowId));
      $res = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

      return $res;
  }

  ?>
  ```
- Include this function (common.php) as common for all pages (or group of pages).
- Then in every page call this function in following format.

  ```
  $resTwo = getRowContentResultSet($_GET['rid']);
  ```
- All the page urls should contain a GET param "rid"
  example: http://yoursite.com/page.php?rid=1

Note: I didnot change your html part. Even that also you can put in a common template.php and just include in your page(s).

Comment: Hi @Dino Excel pls let me know if this helps.